# http module vs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I often see this pattern and now I am curious :

```
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

they use the http module in combination with express, but i learned that you can just use express alone to create a server. What is the reason they use both?

My guess is that you can listen for errors this way? Or is it just an old way of doing things?

Comment: because some libs expect http module like if you want to use `socket.io` with `express `

Answer (score 2):

there are libs expect `http.Server` object like socket.io and to get this `http.Server` you have to call http module `createServer` method

[image]
    var app = require('express')();
    // Right now you are passing express to get routing benefits 
    var http = require('http').createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);